# SQL error when updating member table PDO php

Tags: php, mysql, web, pdo

Afternoon,

Currently I am writing a program that allows an admin to update the members datebase.

My code is as follows:

```
    $member_id = $formdata['update']; 
$surname = $formdata['surname'];
$other_name = $formdata['othername'];
$contactmethod = $formdata['contactmethod'];
$email = $formdata['email'];
$mobilenum = $formdata['mobilenum'];
$phonenum = $formdata['phonenum'];
$occupation = $formdata['occupation'];    
$userpass = $formdata['userpass'];
if(!isset($formdata['magazine']))
   $magazine = 0;
else
   $magazine = 1;

//Get ready to talk to the DB
$db = getDBConnection();
//Make a prepared query so that we can use data binding and avoid SQL injections. 
$insertUser = $db->prepare('INSERT into member VALUES
                          (:surname, :other_name, :contact_method,
                           :email, :mobile, :landline, :magazine, :street,
                           :suburb, :postcode, :password,
                           :occupation) WHERE member_id=$member_id');
//Bind the data from the form to the query variables.
//Doing it this way means PDO sanitises the input which prevents SQL injection.
$insertUser->bindParam(':surname', $surname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insertUser->bindParam(':other_name', $other_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insertUser->bindParam(':contact_method', $contactmethod, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insertUser->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insertUser->bindParam(':mobile', $mobilenum, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insertUser->bindParam(':landline', $phonenum, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insertUser->bindParam(':magazine', $magazine, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$insertUser->bindParam(':street', $streetaddr, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insertUser->bindParam(':suburb', $suburbstate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insertUser->bindParam(':postcode', $postcode, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$insertUser->bindParam(':password', $userpass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insertUser->bindParam(':occupation', $occupation, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Current error is within `WHERE member_id=$member_id`

I have no idea what the error is and how to fix it.

Any tips?

Comment: I believe it may be something along the line that my database requires the member_id to be an int, where currently the $member_id = $formdata['update']; is only a string. However, I can add (int) before the $member_id statement. But even with that changed. I cannot update my database.

Comment: Insert does not use WHERE. You probably want UPDATE. And since you're binding your other variables, bind that member_id as well.

Comment: omg. i didnt even notice that...

Comment: The new `insert where` feature, that's awesome....oooh waiiit!!

Comment: In addition to @aynber's comment. Why would you parameterize 99% of your query and then leave the `WHERE` clause unparameterized?

Comment: What's the error ? Why you don't do :member then bind him like your other variable ?? and you can't insert where, juste insert and update duplicate key

Comment: @Hackerman I've been using it for years! Pfft, get with the times old man :)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, I've been using COBOL for years, oooh look, a meteorite!

Comment: INSERT into member VALUES (:member_id, :surname, :other_name, :contact_method, :email, :mobile, :landline, :magazine, :street, :suburb, :postcode, :password,  :occupation) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE surname ( or wtf is your column name ) = :surname, other_name = :other name [...] WHERE member_id = :member_id ( no sense on duplicate key do this check, so put every condition you want or no condition ). With member_id primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using an UPDATE.

```
'UPDATE member SET surname = :surname, other_name = :other_name, contact_method = :contact_method,
                           email = :email, mobile = :mobile, landline = :landline, magazine = :magazine, street = :street,
                           suburb = :suburb, postcode = :postcode, password = :password,
                           occupation = :occupation) WHERE member_id = :member_id'
```

Additionally, bind another param for member_id otherwise ther isnt much point in doing the others

```
$insertUser->bindParam(':member_id', $member_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```